# Как распечатать документ по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Для того, чтобы распечатать HTML страницу используются ссылки формата:

```html
<a href="javascript:(print());"> Распечатать купон</a>
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы в слайдере на всех страницах по нажатию на ссылку печатался другой документ(jpg или html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите печатать какую-то информацию, к которой есть доступ с текущей страницы, это делается так:
 1. Создаем с помощью js новое окно.
 2. Формируем контент, который хотим печатать. Ну то есть ваш js скрипт должен подготовить какой-то документ для печати.
 3. Пишем контент  в это окно.
 4. Вызваем для этого нового окна метод `print`.

Псевдокод:

```
var windowForPrint = window.open(),
    yourInformation = '';// Сюда что мы хотим печатать.
windowForPrint.document.write(yourInformation); 
windowForPrint.print();
```